# After upgrading to Google Chrome to version 96, shadow-root element search does not work

Tags: python, selenium

After upgrading to Google Chrome to version 96,
shadow-root element search does not work.
In version 93, everything worked fine.

```
ShadowROOTA = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('fse-field-set')
ShadowROOTOpen=browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', ShadowROOTA[0])

text = ShadowROOTOpen.find_elements_by_tag_name('vaadin-text-field')`
```

error:

```
text = ShadowROOTOpen.find_elements_by_tag_name('vaadin-text-field')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a selenium issue targeting this problem: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10019#issuecomment-972671939